# wpa_cli not found on rooted device?

Tags: wi-fi, command-line

I rooted my device, then I go to adb shell and type `su` to enter `wpa_cli`.
I was surprised that `wpa_cli: not found` appeared, although I get information when I type `wpa_supplicant`.

I know that `wpa_cli` is from same library `wpa_supplicant` from this  [link](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/dir_4b5a81f4cd4d61143d67145bf49b62e1.html)

Comment: I guess you really wanted to ask something like "How can I install wpa_cli on my rooted device?"

Comment: @Flow, exactly !! how to do this ?

Comment: I think that this would make a good question. Either edit this question or (maybe even better) ask a new question.

Comment: @Flow already get new question 

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40945/how-can-i-install-wpa-cli-on-my-rooted-device

Answer (score 1):

The wpa_supplicat's command line interface (`wpa_cli`) is not installed as default on most, Android devices. My Galaxy S running CM10 contains it though. I guess you have to manually (compile and) install it.