# How can I install wpa_cli on my rooted device?

Tags: wi-fi, ad-hoc-networks, command-line

I rooted my device, then I go to adb shell and type su to enter wpa_cli. I was surprised that wpa_cli: not found appeared, although I get information when I type wpa_supplicant.

I know that wpa_cli is from same library wpa_supplicant .

Comment: Has anyone found a compiled version of wpa_cli and p2p_cli that work on Android 5.0 and newer?  Binaries require PIE support when compiled...

Answer (score 2):

Install the app: **[WiFi WPS WPA Tester](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tester.wpswpatester&hl=en)** or **[AndroDumpper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigos.androdumpper)**..

It has the latest compiled ***wpa_cli*** binary..
You can get the binary from the app's data from `/data/data`, and you might push it to `/system/bin/` or `/su/bin/` or wherever you need..

---

**Edit**:

Instead, you can use the `wpa_supplicant` binary, which can be found in many devices by default, if that's enough to do what you want..

Or if you wish, [you can compile **wpa_cli** from source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30483146/5002496).

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, wpa_cli will not come along with the Android image. You have to compile and push to Android.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: is it the same commands that Wifi direct used ?