# Which WiFi-Direct commands can be used in Android?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, command-line, wifi-direct

I am interested to know what commands can be used in Android to control WiFi direct from the terminal/command line. I took a look into p2p WIFI direct but I didn't catch these commands!!

I can find commands used with Linux from [this link](http://dishingtech.blogspot.com/2012/01/realtek-wi-fi-direct-programming-guide.html). Can the same be used with Android? If so, how can I access them on a rooted device?

Answer (score 7):

On some devices which do support WiFi-Direct, the corresponding binaries come pre-installed (e.g. the `wpa_cli` command; see also [How can I install wpa_cli on my rooted device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40945/16575)). If you have those ready, you can use them on your Android device as you would do on a Linux machine (find a closer description e.g. in the blog post [How To : Use wpa_cli To Connect To A Wireless Network](http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/27/how-to-use-wpa_cli-to-connect-to-a-wireless-network/)).

Of course that would require a terminal emulator to be installed on your device (take e.g. a look at [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) for a good candidate) -- at least if you want to issue the commands directly.

As the linked "How To" describes, you can use `wpa_cli` in interactive mode (by directly executing it). On the "wpa_cli shell" you then can execute different commands: `scan` scans for available networks, with `add_network` you can select an available network to configure with `set_network`. An example could look like this:

```
> add_network
0
> set_network 0 ssid "WLAN-Network"
> set_network 0 psk "SupahSecretPassphrase"
```

This would trigger a connection phase, which could look like:

```
> <2>Trying to authenticate with 00:55:ab:25:ac:5a (SSID='WLAN-Network' freq=2437 MHz)
> <2>Trying to associate with 00:55:ab:25:ac:5a (SSID='WLAN-Network' freq=2437 MHz)
> <2>Associated with 00:55:ab:25:ac:5a
> <2>WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:55:ab:25:ac:5a [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
> <2>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:55:ab:25:ac:5a completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=]
```

Another good source to take a look at is [Android from the command-line](http://a3nm.net/blog/android_cli.html), which gives some more examples -- not only restricted to WiFi.

Comment: what do you think about previous link that talk about wifi direct commands ?is it not use with android ?

Comment: with only wpa_cli, can i get all require steps as in previous link ?
scan--negotiation-connect-send data ?
also can i have broadcast packets send?

Comment: last question>> does your method require access point ? as soon as WIFI DIRECT doesn't require AP to connect ?

Comment: @Hanaa, please check the linked sources for details -- not having used that stuff myself, I cannot give closer insight. And no, the `wpa_cli` stuff is for WiFi-Direct (at least according to the linked article) and thus does *not* require an AP. As your question was for WiFi-Direct, I restricted my answer to that (and skipped the other stuff).

Comment: ok, but how do android use WIFI DIRECT without install wpa_cli library ??
if they actually use this library ray how they call their kernal with this commands without this library installed ?

Comment: I can't seem to find wpa_cli on devices that do work with GUI WiFi direct.  There also seems to be another tool called p2p_cli - but can't find it either ;)  I only have older binaries that work on Android 4.4 and earlier...  Anyone found newer versions of these shell tools?