# Create persistent wifi direct connection / reconnect after boot

Tags: wifi-direct

I have a Samsung tablet and a Samsung Phone with Android 4.4.2. I can create a wifi direct connection between both devices.

Now I would like to keep this connection after reboot. I know there are persisten groups for this connection and that I can create those with [wpa_cli](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41066/which-wifi-direct-commands-can-be-used-in-android) but I don't have `wpa_cli`, only `wpa_supplicant`.

Is there an app or trick to recreate the wifi direct connection after reboot? Or do I need to root the device and start hacking around with `wpa_cli`?

Comment: did you find any solution to this ?

Comment: I guess you can solve this by rooting and installing wpa_cli. For me wifi was not stable enough. I got USB network adapter (ET-UP900). Needed to compile a new kernel with driver to get the adapter working with the phone. Tablet worked out of the box even after reboot.