# How to setup wifi from adb shell?

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, adb, usb-debugging

I'm using adb over USB to shell into a rooted CyanogenMod-modded device. I wanted to debug my wifi connection through the command line, connecting to an open (unprotected) wifi network. Is it possible to do from adb shell?

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41066/which-wifi-direct-commands-can-be-used-in-android

Comment: I'd close this as a duplicate of that.